# How to add full-text search to SQL Server Express 2019 installation

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-express, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2019-express

I have a local installation of Microsoft SQL Server Express 2019 and just hit the following error:

> Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

So, my understanding is the SQL Server Express supports full-text search, but I need to add components.

According to [one article I found](https://codingsight.com/implementing-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2016-for-beginners/), there is a *New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation* option in SQL Server Express 2016. But I don't have this option in SQL Server Installation Center.

Can anyone tell me how to add full-text support to my installation?

**UPDATE:**

It appears that, while SQL Server Express 2019 does not support full-text search, SQL Server Express 2019 with *Advanced Services* does. So I guess my question is: how do I install Advanced Services?

Comment: Sorry, Jonathan - you're absolutely right - Express with Adv. Services should support full-text search just fine...

Comment: Unless you are using this for production purposes, then the [Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) is also free and fully featured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [this official download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/details.aspx?id=101064) of the Microsoft SQL Server Express web installer. Select "Download Media" and pick the install medium that is right for you.

**Download page**
[image: Download page]

**Web installer** after picking "Download Media"
[image: Web installer]

Comment: Ok, cool. But do I need to reinstall everything? Looks like the option to add advanced services in 2016 may have been removed?

Comment: The web installer has a "Custom Installation" option that might detect your previous installation (cannot validate on my system). My first attempt would be to download the selected medium (796 MB) and run that one. I _would expect_ that installer to detect your current installation and offer options to add features.

Comment: Ok thanks. On further reflection, perhaps I'm better off using the developer edition for this. Guess I need to think this through a little more. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that Custom Installation can detect existing installation and add Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search to it without need for uninstallation or reconfiguration. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone getting an error that `SQLEXPRADV_x64_<LANG>.exe` wasn't found, try switching 'Select Language' to `English`.